# Ignore the warning less of swap partition while preseed loading

Tags: lvm, preseed

I have the automatisation debian preseed script. Here is partition rules with sharps for swap in my preseed file:

```
!d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
      boot-crypto ::                                          \
              512 512 512  ext2                               \
                      $primary{ }                             \
                      $bootable{ }                            \
                      method{ format } format{ }             \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext2 }    \
                      mountpoint{ /boot }                     \
              .                                               \
              1000 20 2000 ext4                             \
                      $defaultignore{ }                       \
                      $lvmok{ } lv_name{ opt }               \
                      in_vg { kaktusvolumegroup }              \
                      method{ format } format{  }             \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ /opt }                      \
              .                                               \
              1000 20 2000 ext4                             \
                      $defaultignore{ }                       \
                      $lvmok{ } lv_name{ home }               \
                      in_vg { kaktusvolumegroup }              \
                      method{ format } format{  }             \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ /home }                      \
              .                                               \
              8000 80 8000 ext4                             \
                      $defaultignore{ }                       \
                      $primary{ }                             \
                      method{ format } format{  }             \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ / }                         \
              .                              
        #      1024 60 1024 swap                             \
        #             $defaultignore{ }                       \
        #              method{ swap } format{  }             \
        #      .
```

[image: IMAGE - do you want proseed the instalation without the swap partition ?]

How to go through that yes\no question and not use typing?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add to preseed-file:

```
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/no_swap boolean false
```